# Teradata: casting varchar to decimal / float

Tags: sql, format, teradata

I need  to convert varchar value like `13,5` to number.
Any code I try returns this: `135,00`

How to make it correctly?

Tried the following:

```
cast('13,5' as float)
cast('13,5' as decimal(18,2))
cast(oreplace('13,5',',','.') as float)
cast(oreplace('13,5',',','.') as decimal(18,2))
cast('13,5' as number)
cast(oreplace('13,5',',','.') as number)
```

Comment: Are you sure the result you're seeing is not a _formatted_ result?

Comment: Decimal comma or decimal point?

Comment: The `oReplace` should work (but `oTranslate` would be more efficient). Or add an NLS parameter to change the decimal seperator to ',': `To_Number('10,5', '99999999999999D99999','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')`

Comment: @dnoeth, hello! Your solution works with one value, but when I try to apply it to the full table, it returns wrong values again. Maybe the problem is that variable contains both whole (like '13') and fractional numbers (like '13,5'). Any idea?

Comment: Cann you show some of the *wrong values* and the source data?

Comment: @dnoeth input = '13,5' (varchar), expected output = '13,5' (number), fact output = '135,00' (number). Fact output is wrong

Comment: Teradata is going to give you the decimal precision you ask for.  `DECIMAL(18,2)` is always going to give you two places after the decimal.

Comment: As I said, the Selects using oReplace will return the correct value. Can you show other values which fail to convert correctly?

Comment: Just replace 13,5 with 13.5 - and you shall be fine.